# I want lldb command give nsarray object of object address

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb, lldb

```
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"AA",nil];
```

I set breakpoint then
if I fire command    po &arr;    on lldb
then i get address of arr variable i want also find address of @"A" object and @"AA" object
How can I find

Comment: With the new syntax you could write NSArray* arr= @[ @"A",@"AA" ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// This will print pointer values
print arr[0]
print arr
print &arr
// This will print object values
po arr
po arr[0]
```

Comment: error: address of property expression requested
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Try with [arr objectAtIndex: 0] instead of arr[0]. arr[0] works for newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 4.6 or later, you could try "frame variable arr[0]".
It will not work on earlier versions, because it is based on synthetic children being provided for NSArray, which is >= 4.6 only